# Encrypt /boot with LUKS 2 on (K)Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, encryption, luks, 20.10

I have a fresh installation of Kubuntu 20.10.
In the installer, I chose the option for full-disk encryption. The partition holding my system (the one mounted at `/`) is now encrypted.

But `/boot` is still un-encrypted. This exposes me to [evil maid attacks](https://github.com/nyxxxie/de-LUKS).

It has been some time since GRUB [supports LUKS 2](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-Boots-LUKS2-Disk-Encrypt).

[The most updated how-to guide for full disk encryption in Ubuntu (including `/boot`) I have found](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) dates back to 2019, would have me to reinstall everything from scratch and it's not updated for `LUKS2`.

I already have the system partition encrypted, now I only need to encrypt /boot.

What are the steps I can follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current grub release is 2.04. from 2017-07-04.
This release offers LUKS1 encryption only.

Do you want to follow the development of luks2-mod?

Do:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/grub.git
cd grub
git log --grep=luks2
# or/and
git log grub-core/disk/cryptodisk.c
# or/and
git log --author=Washburn --author=Steinhardt --author=Kiper
```

And then: Pray to whatever, that $magic comes to us ( the unworthy ^^ )

---

Update:
grub release 2.06 from 2021-06-08 now officially suports devices encrypted using LUKS2. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#cryptomount) you can read basic information about using this functionality (and the knowing restrictions).

Comment: Thank you, I will take your answer as saying that is not currently possible to encrypt `/boot` with LUKS2 out of the box

Comment: @raffaem sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough, but that's what I wanted to say :)